# getValue in EditText - XAMARIN ANDROID

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android

After spend so much hour for find something so simple, finally I must go to here and need somebody help me.

**How can I get the value from EditText in Xamarin, because it's always return null.**

Here is my code:

```
Button loginBtn;
EditText username;
EditText password;
string user;
string pass;
   protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            RequestWindowFeature(Android.Views.WindowFeatures.NoTitle);
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
            // Create your application here
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.LoginForm);

            loginBtn = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.login);
            username = (EditText)FindViewById(Resource.Id.userName);
            password = (EditText)FindViewById(Resource.Id.password);

            user = username.Text.ToString();
            pass = password.Text.ToString();


            loginBtn.Click += (object sender, EventArgs e) =>
            {

                Toast.MakeText(this, user + " : " + pass, ToastLength.Long).Show();
            };
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to move your code inside button click event, because your editexts are in `OnCreate` method and they get value null as `OnCreate` is first method which is called (except if you give them some value in xml code) and you never call your editexts again to actually assign to them users input value. So I think this will resolve your problem:

```
loginBtn.Click += (object sender, EventArgs e) =>
        {
            user = username.Text.ToString();
            pass = password.Text.ToString();
            Toast.MakeText(this, user + " : " + pass, ToastLength.Long).Show();
        };
```